# Expressing multi variable constraints using OR-Tools

Tags: java, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I am exploring Google's Cp-SAT to model a specific type of constraint which looks like following:

Constraints:

Variable X can assume values 1, 2 and 3 
Variable Y can assume values 2, 3 and 4 
Variable Z can assume values 5, 6 and 7 
When variable X value is 1, then Y can only assume 3 or 4 
When variable Y value is 3, then Z can assume only 7

Given variable Y value is 3 and Z value is not 7, find possible values for X and Z.

I was not able to model this using Google's CP-SAT java interface. Can anyone help?

I explored following examples but still not able to figure out:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/samples/LinearProgrammingExample.java

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/samples/SimpleMipProgram.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing solvers (the CP-SAT interface, and the linear solver interface).

You should look at the CP-SAT solver, in particular at this constraint:

http://google.github.io/or-tools/java/classcom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1sat_1_1CpModel.html#a07c24a31bdfe0db93e53fbf38655f200

Please start by reading the introductory documentation:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp

and a list of simple recipes

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/README.md

Comment: Thank you Laurent Perron. That helped a lot.   I have another question: How can I achieve something like this in CP-SAT : (A == i) --> (B == j && C == k), where A,B,C are IntVars and i,j,k are integers.

Comment: Btw I solved  problem similar to question above using following approach:   
    int numVals1 = 3;
    IntVar x1 = model2.newIntVar(0, 1, "x");
    IntVar y1 = model2.newIntVar(0, 2, "y");
    IntVar z1 = model2.newIntVar(0, 2, "z");

    model2.addEquality(y1, 1);
    model2.addDifferent(z1, 0);
    IntVar[] yz = new IntVar[2];
    yz[0] = y1;
    yz[1] = z1;

    int[][] vals = new int[2][2];
    vals[0][0] = 0;
    vals[0][1] = 0;
    vals[1][0] = 1;
    vals[1][1] = 1;
    model2.addAllowedAssignments(yz, vals);
    CpSolverStatus status2 = solver.solve(model2);

Comment: See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md#if-then-else-expressions, the main idea would be to create an intermediate boolean and then `model.Add(B == j).OnlyEnforceIf(boolean)` and `model.Add(C == k).OnlyEnforceIf(boolean)`